# angular js in how use ng-repeat for get api data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, codeigniter

I am new in `angualr js` i want to use `ng-reapet` for my get record display in `td`
below my get record

```
{"Root":[{"Record":["documents.php","OSHA_lockout_regulation.pdf","LOTO_Matrix_2016.docx","LOTO_Log_2016.pdf","Sample_LOTO_policy.pdf","iLockitOut_Help.pdf","Employee_Training.pdf"]}]}
```

how use `ng-reapet` to its **record display**

```
    <tr ng-repeat="(key, list) in documentdetails">
    <td>
        <a class="link" target="_blank" href="../admin/views/documents/{{list.Record[1]}}">{{ list }}</a>
    </td>
    </tr>
```

Please give the suggestion to me

Comment: Can you please format your json response?

Comment: Use list[key].Record[1]

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate like this, `ng-repeat="(key, list) in documents.Root[0].Record"`. If you have more than one `Root`s, you can have nested repeats to achieve same for all of those.

Here's an example. Notice I directly use `{{doc}}` to create your URL.

```js
angular.module("myApp", [])
  .controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.documents = {
      "Root": [{
        "Record": [
          "documents.php",
          "OSHA_lockout_regulation.pdf",
          "LOTO_Matrix_2016.docx",
          "LOTO_Log_2016.pdf",
          "Sample_LOTO_policy.pdf",
          "iLockitOut_Help.pdf",
          "Employee_Training.pdf"
        ]
      }]
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="(key, doc) in documents.Root[0].Record">
      <td>
        <a class="link" target="_blank" href="../admin/views/documents/{{doc}}">{{ doc }}</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/devidas7/HB7LU/28962/) is working fiddle

```
 <tr ng-repeat="(key, document) in documentdetails.Root[0].Record">
  <td>
    <a class="link" target="_blank" href="../admin/views/documents/{{document}}">
    {{ document }}
    </a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

The Controller's code

```
$scope.documentdetails = {  
  "Root":[  
  {  
     "Record":[  
        "documents.php",
        "OSHA_lockout_regulation.pdf",
        "LOTO_Matrix_2016.docx",
        "LOTO_Log_2016.pdf",
        "Sample_LOTO_policy.pdf",
        "iLockitOut_Help.pdf",
        "Employee_Training.pdf"
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```